# Erratic font behavior after upgrading from 27.1 to 29.1 related to --no-x-resources

Tags: fonts, linux, gui-emacs, rendering

After upgrading Emacs from 27.1 to 29.1 yesterday (both compiled from source without configure settings except for `--prefix`) I am seeing erratic behavior of the fonts.

The issue vanishes, when I start as `emacs -Q` and I was able to further narrow it down to the `--no-x-resources` option. I am however unsure, where this issue suddenly comes from, since I do not *have* a user-configured `~/.Xresources` file and can't think of any other source of issues. I am therefore asking for advice how to debug such issues.

**Example.** In the subsequent screenshot I started Emacs with

```
(left)  emacs -q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash
(right) emacs -q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash --no-x-resources
```

where the latter is fully equivalent to `emacs -Q`.

[image]

Note that the selected fonts differ (yellow highlight). Things get crazier, if I try to change them with

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")
```

[image]

Note that the font rendering without `--no-x-resources` no shows noticeable artifacts, that correspond to a lack of anti-aliasing.

Following up with

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "courier")
```

produces a barely even readable font on the left:

[image]

I am basically at a loss here, as to what could have caused this, and why it appears only after upgrading to 29.1; Downgrading back to 27.1 removes the issue too.

For no, using `--no-x-resources` is a viable workaround, but I am worried, that there is some bigger underlying issue on my system.

For completeness: This has been happening on OpenSuse Leap 15.3, using an XFCE desktop.

Comment: So, have you done the obvious thing and listed out what resources Emacs is being given? Install [appres](https://linux.die.net/man/1/appres) and then run `appres emacs`.

Comment: I knew this was Suse almost from the start :-) They have a global Xresources configuration for Emacs that sets the font backend to something like 'xft,x'. Since 29.1 by default uses fontconfig + harfbuzz, there's no xft backend, so Emacs falls back to 'x', which gets you horribly scaled bitmap fonts. You can look at the output of 'xrdb -query' to figure out what resources is being set, and the grep for that.

Comment: Look for 'fontBackend'

Comment: @rpluim In my current GUI session I had run `xrdb /dev/null`, so `xrdb -query` was empty. I tried in a new session, where a *long* list of resources is set up, see https://pastebin.com/YPZxAvie; No "font"-anything is set, but some things relating to Emacs, Xft (see shortened version https://pastebin.com/b45CEyB8). In this session I see the same difference between using `--no-x-resources` and not using it as described above.

Comment: @db48x The [output of `appres emacs`](https://pastebin.com/09zyvWhv) is the same as for [`query -xrdb`](https://pastebin.com/YPZxAvie), except that various lines have been removed (seen by comparing the `sort`-ed version of both). Nothing about that is obvious to me though :/

Comment: BTW, you can check from inside Emacs what the font backend is with `(frame-parameter nil 'font-backend)`